# Loop through this multidimensional array and display as a list of items in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following array. I need to show first_names relevant to each team_name as a list.

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▶]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "team_name" => "Backend"
    "description" => "Laravel is used"
    "created_at" => "2021-05-29 07:17:32"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-31 02:16:50"
    "get_employees" => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "team_name" => "Backend"
        "first_name" => "Test1"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "team_name" => "Backend"
        "first_name" => "Test2"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "team_name" => "Backend"
        "first_name" => "Test3"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▼
        "team_name" => "Backend"
        "first_name" => "Test4"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▶]
  3 => array:6 [▶]
  4 => array:6 [▶]
  5 => array:6 [▶]
  6 => array:6 [▶]
]
```

As this way.

```
Team name:- Backend  

People:- Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4
```

Below is my code block in blade.php but it gives me the error 'Trying to get property 'team_name' of non-object'. I tried several methods but was failed to create the loop.

```
@foreach($teamEmployees as $key => $teamArray){
   {{$key->team_name}}
        @foreach($teamArray as $team_Array)
            {{$teamArray['get_employees'][0]['first_name']}}
        @endforeach
}
@endforeach
```

This is my controller function if it is useful in any case.

```
public function teamsWithEmployee(){
        $teamEmployees=Teams::with(['get_employees'=>function($query){
            $query->select(['team_name','first_name']);
        }])->get()->toArray();
         dd ($teamEmployees);
       return view('teams-employee', compact('teamEmployees'));
     }
```

I am very new to PHP and Laravel. Previous questions on this type didn't help me to solve this. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access `'team_name'` as arra key. And you can loop through the nested array via recursive templates:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <div style="margin-left:10px;">
        Team name: {{ $project['team_name'] }}
        @if (array_key_exists('first_name', $project)
            {{ $project['first_name'] }}
        @end
        @if(array_key_exists('get_employees', $project) && count($project['get_employees']))
            @include('projects', [ 'projects' => $project['get_employees'] ])
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks:) But this giving me error 'View [projects] not found'. I changed my array name to $projects also.

Comment: You're welcome :) It should have the same name as the template you're using.

Comment: This only gives the team_name. each employees are not displaying

Comment: I added that to my answer.